# Get and Post methods in Lua

Tags: post, authentication, get, lua, gideros

I need a method in Lua. This method should work like post and get methods which exist in php.
I need it to build a simple login page with lua. What i need to do it with Lua?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Lua is normally embeded in to something,  what environment are you running in?

Comment: I don't know it, but have you looked at the URLLoader Class http://www.giderosmobile.com/forum/discussion/comment/10127#Comment_10127

Comment: There is no post and get methods in php. You are referencing to the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [Luasockets](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html)?
Apparently gideros has [luasocket installed](http://appcodingeasy.com/Gideros-Mobile/Using-LuaSocket-in-Gideros).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to act as a web server, you will probably need something like Xavante.

Other than that, beforementioned luasockets has some HTTP functions; you should look at its documentation.